# Going to an activity when a videoview is touched

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-videoview

I have a videoview, where a video is being played. I want to stop the video and return back  when the videoview is touched.
I think I have to do this.

```
           videoView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                videoView.stopPlayback();
          // Here I have to implement the code to go back???

                return true;
            }
        });
```

onBackPressed, startActivity() -> They are not accessible. How do I implement the going back functionality?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you call finish() your current activity ?

Comment: @android_Muncher: No, I can't.

Comment: @Droidy are you using fragments?

Comment: No fragments. Just activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this in your current activity declare an activity object like:

```
public static Activity mActivityObj;
```

And in your `onCrate()`
add this line:

```
mActivityObj = this;
```

Then inside your method add the following code:

```
videoView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                videoView.stopPlayback();
                // Here I have to implement the code to go back???
                YourActivity.mActivityObj.finish();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

That not much difficult. What you need is:

1) Stop the video playing.

2) Return to some activity.

**Ans 1)** For stopping the video from being played, the `mAdVideoView.stopPlayback();` will stop  the video.

**Ans 2)** Return to some activity:
       Two ways again here depending upon your requirement.

1) If you wish to return back to previous screen or activity, just call `finish()` method

2) If you wish to navigate to a new activity use `Intents`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent); // for Navigating to a Target activity.
getActivity().finish(); // for finishing the current activity
```

Comment: startActivity() and finish() are inaccessible.

Comment: try using getActivity().startActivity() and getActivity().finish(). This should help you.

Comment: startActivity(), finish() or getActivity().startActivity(), getActivity().finish() are not accessible either.